# Select rows where Specific ID & List Name Price in column higher price than same column?

Tags: sql, hadoop

I have something like below:

```
ID - LIST_NAME - PRICE  
1 - WASIA - 100  
1 - GASIA - 150  
2 - WSPAIN - 150  
3 - GMIAMI - 125  
2 - GSPAIN - 100  
2 - GMIAMI - 150  
2 - WMIAMI - 125
```

I would like the output to be:

```
2 - WSPAIN - 150  
2 - GSPAIN - 100
```

Since the W-version is higher price than the G version.
Event better would be if it could basically show both on the same row:

```
2 - WSPAIN - 150 - GSPAIN - 100
```

There can be many many occurrences of ID for different LIST_NAME, An ID does not have to have every LIST_NAME (ex. 3 does not have WMIAMI)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using a self `join` with `stuff` (replaces the first character with a blank to compare):

```
select t1.id, t1.list_name, t1.price, t2.list_name, t2.price
from yourtable t1
    join yourtable t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t1.price > t2.price and
    left(t1.list_name,1) = 'W' and
    left(t2.list_name,1) = 'G' and
    stuff(t1.list_name,1,1,'') = stuff(t2.list_name,1,1,'')
```